# Problems with decrypting in RSA (Python)

Tags: python, rsa

I just wrote a small python Programm that uses RSA en- and decryption. It's just for fun. My Problem is that it never finished decrypting, witch is obviously not intended. d is berry large and I'm not sure if it is even able to decrypt. Is there a logic mistake? Did I miss something? The generatePrimes Funktion generates primes with bitlength 512.

```
from generatePrime import generatePrime


from math import gcd as bltin_gcd

def coprime(a, b):
    return bltin_gcd(a, b) == 1

def encript(msg,e,N):
    print("encripting :")
    return msg**e % N

#THIS HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
def decript(en,d,N):
    print("decripting :")
    pow(en, d, N) #Like this?


def RSA():
    print("generating P     ")
    P = generatePrime()
    print("generating Q ")
    Q = generatePrime()
    print("calculating N ")
    N = P* Q
    print("calculating phi ")
    phi = (Q-1)*(P-1)
    e = 65537
    if not coprime(e,P) and not coprime(e,Q):
        RSA()
    d = int((1+ phi)/e)
    #print(d)

    encripted = encript(16468,e,N)
    print(encripted)
    decripted = decript(encripted,d,N)
    print(decripted)
    print("sucsess!")

RSA()
print("Done!")
```

d is huge but it has to be doesn't it? I have no clue.

This is the generatePrime Funktion (witch I stole)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import random
import math


def fermat_primality_test(p, s=5):
    """
    a^(p-1) ≡ 1 mod p
    Input: prime candidate p and security paramter s
    Output: either p is a composite (always trues), or
            p is a prime (with probability)
    """
    if p == 2:
        return True
    if not p & 1: # if p is even, number cant be a prime
        return False

    for i in range(s):
        a = random.randrange(2, p-2)
        x = pow(a, p-1, p) # a**(p-1) % p
        if x != 1:
            return False
    return True

def square_and_multiply(x, k, p=None):
    """
    Square and Multiply Algorithm
    Parameters: positive integer x and integer exponent k,
                optional modulus p
    Returns: x**k or x**k mod p when p is given
    """
    b = bin(k).lstrip('0b')
    r = 1
    for i in b:
        r = r**2
        if i == '1':
            r = r * x
        if p:
            r %= p
    return r

def miller_rabin_primality_test(p, s=5):
    if p == 2: # 2 is the only prime that is even
        return True
    if not (p & 1): # n is a even number and can't be prime
        return False

    p1 = p - 1
    u = 0
    r = p1  # p-1 = 2**u * r

    while r % 2 == 0:
        r >>= 1
        u += 1

    # at this stage p-1 = 2**u * r  holds
    assert p-1 == 2**u * r

    def witness(a):
        """
        Returns: True, if there is a witness that p is not prime.
                False, when p might be prime
        """
        z = square_and_multiply(a, r, p)
        if z == 1:
            return False

        for i in range(u):
            z = square_and_multiply(a, 2**i * r, p)
            if z == p1:
                return False
        return True

    for j in range(s):
        a = random.randrange(2, p-2)
        if witness(a):
            return False

    return True

def generatePrime(n=512, k=1):
    """
    Generates prime numbers with bitlength n.
    Stops after the generation of k prime numbers.
    Caution: The numbers tested for primality start at
    a random place, but the tests are drawn with the integers
    following from the random start.
    """
    assert k > 0
    assert n > 0 and n < 4096

    # follows from the prime number theorem
    necessary_steps = math.floor( math.log(2**n) / 2 )
    # get n random bits as our first number to test for primality
    x = random.getrandbits(n)

    primes = []

    while k>0:
        if miller_rabin_primality_test(x, s=7):
            primes.append(x)
            k = k-1
        x = x+1

    return primes[0]
```

I did try:

```
from Crypto.Util import number
def generatePrime(len=512):
    return number.getPrime(len)
```

But that didn't solve the Problem.

Comment: What is generatePrim?

Comment: I added the geberatePrime Funktion. As I said I didn't write it myself but as far as I see it works fine. I tested it and it does output a large number but if converted to string and than passed throug the Len() Funktion, it only outputs (I think) 151. (Not sure but the 512 bitlength is the output number in binary, if you get what I mean...)

Comment: Your algorithm is trying to compute numbers such as ``(10 ** 306) ** (10 ** 302)`` (rounded to pow ten because the comment length limit is too small). In technical terms, this is a frigging huge number. Don't expect it get done in a realistic time.

Comment: In line with @MisterMiyagi's comments, get rid of every operation that looks like this: `en**d % N` and replace it by using the three argument form of [`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow), like this `pow(en, d, N)`.

Comment: def decript(en,d,N):
 print("decripting :")
 return pow(en, d, N)  #  --> Is that correct now? The programm does now finish but the result isn't the msg(message) but a large number?

Comment: When I use P = 3, Q = 11, e = 3 (which are numbers from an example online, it works without problems. There must be something wrong with generatePrimes then?!

Comment: Well, ``generatePrime`` only has a chance of providing primes. It doesn't guarantee to provide primes. It is even explicitly documented as such.

Comment: But the chance of failing every time is pretty low isn't it? I tried generating primes with number.getPrime(512) from the crypto library but it fails nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I got it to work.
This is my final code:

```
om RSAresources import *

class RSA:

    def __init__(self,msg,e=65537,P=generatePrime(),Q = generatePrime()):

        self.e = e
        self.P = P
        self.Q = Q
        self.msg = msg

        while not coprime(e,P) and not coprime(e,Q):
            self.P = generatePrime()
            self.Q = generatePrime()

        self.N = P * Q
        self.phi = (Q-1)*(P-1)
        self.d = mod_inverse(self.e,self.phi)

    def encript(self):
        return pow(self.msg,self.e, self.N)

    def decript(self):
        return pow(self.msg,self.d,self.N)
```

This is RSAresources.py:

```
from Crypto.Util import number

def generatePrime(leng=1024):
    return number.getPrime(leng)

def mod_inverse(x,y):

    def eea(a,b):
        if b==0:return (1,0)
        (q,r) = (a//b,a%b)
        (s,t) = eea(b,r)
        return (t, s-(q*t) )

    inv = eea(x,y)[0]
    if inv < 1: inv += y
    return inv


from math import gcd as bltin_gcd

def coprime(a, b):
    return bltin_gcd(a, b) == 1
```

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what was wrong? This code seems quite different from the one in the question.

Comment: Yes, I can. It is the same code, but in class structure. I was calculating d wrong. I have no idea where I got the formula from, that I used in my original code, but it is wrong. You have to calculate the modular inverse with e and phi(N). It works great now.